# demeaning or differentiation in fixed-effect equation

Tags: autocorrelation, stata, fixed-effects-model, unbiased-estimator, consistency

I have panel data (with short time-dimension $T>2$) and I consider a simple model of the form:
$$y_{i,t} = x_{i,t} \beta + c_i + \epsilon_{i,t}$$
where $E(x_{i,s}\epsilon_{i,t})=0$ and $\epsilon_{i,t}$ are iid and of mean 0.

To get rid  of the $c_i$ and to estimate the $\beta$, one can consider in particular:

- either first differentiating succesive observations and then performing an OLS regression: $\Delta y_{i,t} = (\Delta x_{i,t}) \beta +\Delta \epsilon_{i,t}$
- or demeaning and then performing an OLS regression: $y_{i,t} - \bar{y_{i,t}} = (x_{i,t} - \bar{x_{i,t}}) \beta +(\epsilon_{i,t}-\bar{\epsilon_{i,t}})$

Please note that the demeaning seems to be prefered (it is the "fixed-effect estimator"), and it can be written (for instance here*) that "The [first difference] estimator is slightly less efficient than the [demeaning], as $\Delta \epsilon$ exhibits serial correlation, even if $\epsilon_{i,t}$’s are uncorrelated." For instance demeaning is used in the Stata command xtreg, fe.

**My first question** is: **why should the demeaning approach should be prefered to the differentiating approach?**

**As a temptative answer**, it is indeed easy to see that $\Delta \epsilon_{i,t}$ is correlated with $\Delta \epsilon_{i,t+1}$ as both terms share $\epsilon_{i,t}$. It comes: $cov(\Delta \epsilon_{i,t+1},\Delta \epsilon_{i,t}) = - \sigma_\epsilon<0$

However, both $(\epsilon_{i,t}-\bar{\epsilon_{i,t}})$ and $(\epsilon_{i,t+1}-\bar{\epsilon_{i,t}})$ also share the terme $\bar{\epsilon_{i,t}}$ (and this term includes also $\frac{\epsilon_{i,t}}{T}$ and $\frac{\epsilon_{i,t+1}}{T}$). It comes: $cov(\epsilon_{i,t}-\bar{\epsilon_{i,t}},\epsilon_{i,t+1}-\bar{\epsilon_{i,t}}) = - \frac{2}{T}(1-\frac{1}{T}) \sigma_\epsilon^2<0$

Hence, my understanding is that there is also some correlation after applying demeaning, but less than when applying first-differencing. This is why it is better.

**My second (highly related) questions** are: am I making a mistake above? If not, **what is the impact of these correlations on the estimates of the $\beta$?** Thank you in advance!

*see http://statmath.wu.ac.at/~hauser/LVs/FinEtricsQF/FEtrics_Chp5.pdf in page 25 for demeaning, and in page 28 for first differentiating.

Comment: Bounty expires in 3 days, and there is still no answer. If someone has a suggestion to make the question more understandable/readable/attractive, please make it in comments! thank you in advance. Regards.

Comment: I guess there are rather few people who are active on Cross Validated at the moment and who work on panel data. You might have better luck on Economics Stack Exchange (though I am little familiar with the current situation there).

Comment: Demeaning (fixed effects) does not dominate first differences. The assumptions under which they identify $\beta$ are different (though the difference is minor and irrelevant in practice except in the case of a dynamic regression model), and the assumptions under which either efficient (smallest asymptotic variance) are very different. A very detailed discussion developing these conclusions can be found in Chapters 10 and 11 in Wooldridge's Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data, if you can't get that I might be able to write this up later.

Comment: @CloseToC : Thank you (really!) for the reference!!! Section 10.7.1 of "Wooldridge's Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data" is indeed: Comparison of Fixed Estimators - FE vs Demeaning. If I do understand him correctly, he notably states that demeaning is more efficient when $\epsilon_{i,t}$ are i.i.d., but the differencing is more efficient when $\epsilon_{i,t}$ follows a random walk. However, note that I restricted the question to the first case.

Answer (score 1):

Both the first difference transformation and the within transformation generate serial correlation in the estimated residuals even when it is not there in the underlying data generating process. For $T > 2$, the first difference estimator is less efficient than the within if the error term is really iid. For $T = 2$ the first differences estimator and the within estimator are equivalent.

The first difference estimator requires a slightly weaker assumption than strict exogeneity, namely that the transitory component of the error term is uncorrelated with the conditioning variables in the current period, as well as one period before and one period after (rather than all of them). This will not matter in most economic contexts.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer that appears correct to me. I awarded the bounty to @IMA as I think her/his answer helps me better to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it more efficient?

Let $e$ denote the transformed error from either transformation. We have that
$$V(\hat{\beta}|X)=(X'X)^{-1}X'V(e|X)X(X'X)^{-1}$$

So looking at $V(e|X)$, we check diagonal and off-diagonal elements. For diagonal elements, we have $2\sigma^2$ for the first-difference, and for the within transform $\sigma^2+V(\overline{\epsilon}(T))$ where the latter term goes towards zero with at a rate of $T^2$.

For the off-diagonal elements, you have already checked that the within transform becomes more efficient with $T$ for all elements.

Check for example $T=3$, where the estimators differ. On the diagonal, you have for the first-difference $2\sigma^2$. But for the within estimator, the diagonal comes out as $\sigma^2+\frac{1}{4}(2\sigma^2)=\frac{3}{2}\sigma^2$ which is less than $2\sigma^2$.
You can do the same for other elements and for larger $T$.

In that sense, the estimator is more efficient, it provides smaller standard errors for the same data generating process.

Edit: You can calculate this out (I think the exact formula is not so important in this case), but say you will get something like

$$V(\hat{\beta}|x)=\frac{\sum_{t,h}x_{t}x_h \sigma_{t,h}}{2\sum_t x_t^2}$$ and then obviously that thing is declining in $T$ for the within estimator, meaning it makes use of the additional data we have if $T>2$ whereas the difference estimator is constant and thereby not efficient over $T$

Comment: First, thanks for this answer!

Comment: Second (and not very important), I get that $\sigma^2+V(\overline{\epsilon}(T)) = \sigma^2 - \frac{\sigma^2}{T}$. So I would say that the convergence rate is $\frac{1}{T}$ rather than $\frac{1}{T^2}$. Am I correct?

Comment: Third, regarding the off-diagonal elements, I realized by reading your answer that some are zero for the first difference while they are non-zero for the demeaning (for instance for $cov(e_t,e_{t-2})$. It is 0 for the first difference, but $-\frac{2}{T}(1-\frac{1}{T})\sigma$ for the demeaning).)

Comment: I award the bounty as I think your answer is the one that brings me a very good understanding of how to deal with the problem. Please do not hesitate to look at (and answer) my above comments. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey, sorry for answering late. Second, yes, take all my calculations with a grain of salt, I did not double check ;-) Point is that there is convergence in this element of the cov-matrix.
Third, you are correct about zero elements, and so its not cut-and dry for any sample size. But efficiency in this case means that the variance converges for the within estimator over T and you can do the same calculations for other configurations such as with more regressors, a panel etc. But I think the idea is quite clear - something dependent on an average will converge with T, the other thing not

Comment: Edit: Also as noted above, this all depends on how the within estimator behaves compared to the FD estimator. In your case, what I wrote is true, but it doesn't hold for every distribution (see Woolridge).